# Is there a specific reason why I could be getting a "relation error" when running my migrations with knex?

Tags: postgresql, express, database-migration, knex.js

I am trying to run my migration tables with knex and I keep getting a relation error. Here I have attached my code and the error I am getting.

This is a backend for a full stack web application using Knex, Express and PostgreSQL. I can't seem to understand why my "id" in the "fish" table does not exist. If you look at the "user_post" table, I reference the id in "fish" table as a foreign key. Somewhere in my "user_post" table I am doing something wrong. Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you.

[my table named "fish"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Es1tM.jpg)

[my table named "user_post"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A4tlm.jpg)

[the error I am getting when I try to run my migrations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Wcp1.jpg)

I should expect the migrations to run, but my foreign key which is "id" in the table "fish" does not exist.

Comment: Why dont't you create new make migration for alter_user_post_table and add foreign key constraint in it.

Comment: Just fixed it, I did not know that if you add a foreign key to a table that has not already been built yet, it has no idea about the table. Because users_posts was built before user, user_post has no information on user. I also figured out that user is a reserved word in psql, so switching the names to users and users_post fixed the problem.